# Create two levels of multiindex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I can create a df and then modify it to have a two level column index as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two', 'three']])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 6), index=idx, columns=['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'])
print(df, '\n')

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A'], df.columns])
print(df.head(3))
```

I get this:

```
                  A                                                  
                  C         D         E         F         G         H
bar one   -0.370228  1.246188  0.673553  0.116890  0.129511  0.126562
    two   -1.059752 -0.357985 -0.189913  1.080814  0.588176  0.212053
    three -0.345277 -1.227097  0.915477  1.475285 -1.342885  0.149785
```

But what I want is this:

```
                  A                             B                      
                  C         D         E         F         G         H
bar one   -0.370228  1.246188  0.673553  0.116890  0.129511  0.126562
    two   -1.059752 -0.357985 -0.189913  1.080814  0.588176  0.212053
    three -0.345277 -1.227097  0.915477  1.475285 -1.342885  0.149785
```

So that my columns are accessed as:  AC, AD, AE, BF, BG, BH

I have tried this (and a few other things):

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[['A'], df[['C', 'D', 'E']]], [['B'], df[['F', 'G', 'H']]]])
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How can I create the multi-index in the way that I desire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply assign a two-dimensional array as the dataframe's columns:

```
df.columns = [
    ['A']*3 + ['B']*3,
    ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
]
```

Result:

```
                  A                             B                    
                  C         D         E         F         G         H
bar one   -0.682664  0.221460 -0.595096 -0.327291  0.997758 -0.100819
    two    0.698674 -0.433741  1.572080  0.849064  0.666364 -0.313989
    three -0.597167  0.322044 -0.693410  1.551602  0.718136 -0.881298
baz one    0.701170 -0.164332  0.111689  0.192714 -0.743848 -1.447928
    two    0.504745 -0.059556 -1.673365  0.734746  0.586669  1.541826
```